# May a South African access the Zurich Airport Transit Hotel without a Swiss visa?

Tags: transit-visas, accommodation, south-african-citizens, zrh

I am a South African citizen with an eight hour layover in Zurich on my way home from Ireland/UK.

Is it possible to make use of the [Transit Hotel](https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/layover-and-lounges/transit-hotel-bedrooms) without a Swiss visa?

I did try to access the airport (not the hotel part) on a prior occasion coming back from Ireland and was told to go straight to my very depressing departure gate.

Comment: @JonathanReez perhaps OP wants to know whether the hotel is "airside," or, more precisely, in the "international" part of the airport. That question and hers are essentially equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanReez She wasn't previously trying to reach the hotel specifically, just to "access the airport." By this I assume she means to pass through immigration control either to the Schengen gates or the unsecured arrival or departure areas.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is airside [at Gates B/D, Level 1](https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/layover-and-lounges/transit-hotel-bedrooms):

[image: Transit Hotel]
*Image [courtesy](https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/layover-and-lounges/transit-hotel-bedrooms)*

> Location / opening times
>
> You can find us at Gates B/D, Level 1. The Transit Hotel Reception is
>   staffed 24 hours a day .
>
> The boarding pass check and security check are open until 10.30 p.m.,
>   the passport check until 11 p.m. and as of 6 a.m. (Access possible
>   only with a boarding card and only with hand luggage). No access
>   to/from the Schengen area between 11 p.m. and 6 a.m. from/to the
>   Transit Hotel.